# How can I retain the contents on either side of my split delimiter RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to split a string containing multiple names in the format `Surname, First Name(s),Surname, First Name(s)` with a comma with no white-space on either side as the delimiter:

```
var input = 'White, Sterling M.,Devinney, Michael,Bernal, Tracy';

input.split(/[^ ]{1},[^ ]{1}/g); //Outputs: ["White, Sterling M", "evinney, Michae", "ernal, Tracy"]
```

How can I retain/include the character on either side of the comma? It doesn't necessarily need to be a `split`, that's just the closest to a result as I've come.

**Note:** In case you're wondering, I get this list as-is from another system, so I don't have the option to change the string I'm given to something easier to parse.

Any help would be kindly appreciated!

Comment: This is not possible in Javascript because of how `split` works, and the lack of support of regex lookbehinds. Would be it ok to check if only the following character isn't a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need lookbehind assertions to do this with a `.split()`, and JavaScript doesn't support those. But you can match instead of splitting:

```
result = input.match(/(?: ,|, |[^,])+/g);
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:    # Start of group that matches either...
 [ ],  # a space followed by a comma
|      # or
 ,[ ]  # a comma, followed by a space
|      # or
 [^,]  # any character except a comma
)+     # one or more times.
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qQ3uO8).

Comment: Great! Thanks, Tim. Exactly what I was going for — And bonus points for explaining how it works which taught me something I didn't know about regex'es (start of group).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `/,(?=[^ ])/`:

```
"White, Sterling M.,Devinney, Michael,Bernal, Tracy".split(/,(?=[^ ])/);

Output on Chrome console:
["White, Sterling M.", "Devinney, Michael", "Bernal, Tracy"]
```

You just check for a `,` where the following char is not a space.
While JS doesn't support lookbehinds, it supports lookaheads and as I understand your question this is what you need.

Comment: Nice! You've adjusted my question to better fit the use-case *and* it does indeed work with `split` only. I'll have to just give you an up-vote since @Tim technically answered more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var input = new String('White, Sterling M.,Devinney, Michael,Bernal, Tracy');

var test = input.split(/[^ ]{1},[^ ]{1}/g);

for(var i = 0; i < (test.length-1); i++) {
    alert(test[0]);
    alert(test[1]);
    alert(test[2]);             
}
```